# Opening yelp deep link from android app

Tags: android, deep-linking, yelp

I am using the following code and it is not opening the yelp app:

```
    String uriString = "yelp://biz/" + "some name"; 
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString)));
```

Instead it says

> Could not execute method of the activity !

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer being, just call the http url of the yelp page, it will ask you whether to open in yelp app if it is pre-installed. Else , it will just open in the browser.